# How to customize sign-in screen when lock screen is disabled?

Tags: windows-10-v1703

In Windows 10 Creators Update (1703), you can choose to "Show lock screen background picture on the sign-in screen". However, when you disable the lock screen (e.g., using the `NoLockScreen` setting in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization`), the lock screen customization settings are locked completely, which looks like this:
[image]

So how do you customize the sign-in screen when the lock screen is disabled this way? Is there a better way to disable the lock screen which does not disable the lock screen (and hence sign-in screen) customization options?

Before posting comments or answers, please familiarize yourself with the difference between the lock screen and the sign-in screen (e.g., [here](https://www.isunshare.com/blog/windows-10-login-screen-vs-lock-screen/)). Also, make sure that your answer applies to the Creators Update: `NoLockScreen` worked in initial builds of Windows 10 (1507/1511), was gone in 1607, and was reactivated in 1703. It is not clear to me whether it worked identically in 1507/1511 as it does in 1703.

Comment: Have you tried to enable that registry setting, then make the desired changes, and then disable that registry setting?

Comment: @LPChip yes, that works (that is, DISabling the setting [`NoLockScreen=0` is default]; making changes, ENabling it again). But every change requires logging off and on again, so this is a bit tedious.

Comment: Well, you only need to set it to 0, make changes, test until satisfied, then set the setting to 1.

Comment: @LPChip ... and repeat that as often as you get bored by the current image ;) by the way, Windows spotlight, which automatically rotates between lock screen (and thus sign-in screen) images, is also disabled; ideally, I would just like to use Windows spotlight for sign-in screen backgrounds.

Comment: Why do you want to disable the lock screen anyway? If its due to not wanting to enter a password, in windows 10 you can actually change it to not require you to unlock with a password, but a single click. That should get you the best of both worlds.

Comment: @LPChip you are confusing the lock screen with the sign-in screen. Disabling the lock screen gets rid of the need to swipe up the lock screen to access the sign-in screen; it does not change the sign-in screen, or the sign-in process, otherwise.

Comment: Hmm, I think I actually am...